# JAVA / JAI on Ubuntu 11 (64 bit)?

Tags: java, ubuntu

Can I install Java 7 from Oracle (jre and jdk) on Ubuntu 11 (64 bit)?
I heard that Sun Java is dropped and I have to use openJDK. Is that right?
And what about JRE?

**EDIT**

I downloaded JAI and ImageIO files then follow these instructions:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html#installing-native-jai-on-linux
but when I run it with:

```
sudo sh jai-1_1_3-lib-linux-amd64-jre.bin
sudo sh jai-1_1_3-lib-linux-amd64-jdk.bin
```

I got the error:

```
this is not a proper jdk directory. exiting install.
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that OpenJDK is available through the package system but I cannot remember if Java 7 is included in Ubuntu 11.

`apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk`  for Java 6, and `apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` for Java 7.

If you cannot use OpenJDK but must use Oracle or IBM implementations you download those and set up your PATH and JAVA_HOME variables manually.

Answer (score 1):

> I downloaded jre and jdk from Oracle. Then when I run it with:
>
> ```
> sudo sh jai-1_1_3-lib-linux-amd64-jre.bin
> sudo sh jai-1_1_3-lib-linux-amd64-jdk.bin
> ```

What you've downloaded isn't the JRE or JDK but the [Java Advanced Imaging library](http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/README.html).

> Can I install Java 7 from Oracle (jre and jdk) on Ubuntu 11 (64 bit)?
>   I heard that Sun Java is dropped and I have to use openJDK. Is that
>   right? And what about JRE?

Which Ubuntu 11? There are two releases per year, in April and October: 11.04 (Natty) and 11.10 (Oneiric). The `openjdk-7-jdk` and `openjdk-7-jre` packages are available from Ubuntu 11.10.

The Sun/Oracle JDK/JRE was dropped from the main distribution for licensing reasons. The OpenJDK JDK and JRE are very similar to the Sun/Oracle JDK and JRE (most of the code base is shared), although you may find that some of the releases may lag behind when it comes to Ubuntu packaging. For example, Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid) is still providing OpenJDK 6b20, which is quite behind the latest Oracle Java 6 release (update 32), which provided various fixes, including for security-related problems (although a number of security patches were back-ported).

If you want to use the OpenJDK, install the `openjdk-7-jdk` and `openjdk-7-jre` packages (provided that you're at least running Ubuntu 11.10).

Otherwise, you can download the Oracle JRE/JDK binary packages from this address: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: i use Ubuntu 11.10 .. So, you recommend that i better use openjdk rather than oracle one ?

Comment: thank you.. i installed jre/jdk but now i can't get the JAI and ImageIO work.. i did edit my post.

Comment: Not sure, maybe it needs to be run within the Java home directory, perhaps `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk`

Comment: mine is usr/local/java .. this directory contains jre and jdk .. still not working

Comment: @Shadin: are you sure JAI is still active an supported with modern JRE/JDKs? Even the latest development revisions seem to date back to more than 4 years: http://java.net/projects/jai-core/sources/svn/show

Comment: i just noticed that. i don't know if these JAIs is still supported with oracle java or Ubuntu 11.10 .. i have no idea what should i do